# Speech recognition not available in ios9

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, speech-recognition

Use speech recognition api to build an IOS app. but it's only working in IOS10. is it possible to disable speech recognition function in IOS9. or I need build 2 app. one in IOS10 with speech recognition, and one in previous platforms without the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the framework optional. In XCode go to project settings, then Build Phases, Link Binaries with Libraries and then set status to optional instead of required for Speech framework. Then, in your code you will have to check if relevant classes are available so that your app doesn't crash in iOS 9.